# How to get some View in Android from addOnItemTouchListener in RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I have created an extra class for implementing listener on RecyclerView, but it refers on the whole view of row and i want also to have listener for one View in that row which is in this case button.

I know that i can get access to that view from CustomViewHolder, but the problem is that i can't pass some values from adapter to an activity where is adapter called.

How could i get this View from `addOnItemTouchListener`? Here is the code:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), list, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            // Is it possible to check which view is clicked here
            // Something like this
            if (view == findViewById(R.id.btn)) {
               // do something
               // but this is not working.
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

Or any other suggestion who can i achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you could create your Callback listener in such way

```
public interface OnRecyclerRowListener {
    void onClick(int position, View v);

    void onLongClick(int position, View v);
}
```

let your activity implement it and pass an instance to it to your adapter and within your adapter `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        onRecyclerRowListener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(),v);
    }
});
```

Comment: But how to get outside the adapter listener for some view inside the row of list? Button for example?